# Memcache on MAMP 1.9

Tags: mamp, memcache

I am trying to make memcache work on MAMP 1.9. In the process I have successfully installed memcached and tested it. But I can't find a way to install memcache.so on my MAMP. Any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem today. I tried installing the memcache module using PECL and it turns out that PECL is compiling the module to a 64bit architecture. You can check the architecture by:

```
file /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so
```

My result (working) is now this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so (for architecture i386): Mach-O bundle i386
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so (for architecture x86_64):       Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

Previously it was just:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so (for architecture x86_64):       Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

I followed the steps in [Matthias Schmidt's blog](http://blog.m-schmidt.eu/2010/03/30/develop-memcached-web-apps-with-xampp-under-mac-os-x/). The tutorial is for XAMPP but it should be the same (more or less) with MAMP.

Comment: Thanks. Can't give you 1 up, I don;t have enough points. But your solution worked perfectly.